# Row-wise selection based on multiple conditions in dask?

Tags: python, numpy, dask

What is the most performant way in dask to select rows based on multiple conditions? In pandas, something like

```
df[df.A > 0 & df.B <= 10]
```

does work. In dask, however, this will return an error. The best solution I came up with so far is to use numpys `logical_and()`function:

```
df[np.logical_and(df.A > 0, df.B <= 10)]
```

However, this is super slow as it triggers several computes (I assume). Is there any more performant way to select rows in dask based on multiple conditions?

Comment: The above will also not work in pandas, you need parantheses: ``df[(df.A > 0) & (df.B <= 10)]``

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the hint of @joris, parenthesis at the right position work. So the solution in dask is similar/identical to the pandas solution:

```
df[(df.A > 0) & (df.B <= 10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
df[df.A > 0][df.B <= 10]
```

which is equivalent to logical AND

Comment: This will not give the desired result, as for the second boolean indexing your dataframe is shorter due to the first boolean indexing.

Comment: since you don't reindex this is equivalent to `df[(df.A > 0) & (df.B <= 10)]`

Comment: Ah  yes, that's right. But performance wise (and in case of using dask that will mater), you will want the `df[(df.A > 0) & (df.B <= 10)]` case to avoid reindexing.